# How to save Login Info in flutter web-view app, so it is not required to login every-time

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a simple webview app. Whenever i open the app i have to provide the username and password,. is there any way to save username and password in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference to save data locally like user name and password..
Package: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences. I am assuming you are having logout button to logout from app, till then shared preferences will store data and user will be logged in.